# CouchDB Continuous Filtered Replication - UserCtx Change

Tags: couchdb

I am doing Continuous Filtered Replication between DB1 (source) and DB2 (target). The filter logic is based on user's role (user context). Here is my scenario:

In _users database, for user1 role is [project1]
I start the continuous filtered replication.
Do any change in project1 in DB1, it gets replicated to DB2
Change user1 role (in _users db) from [project1] to [project1,project2]
Do any change in project2 in DB1, it doesnt get replicated to DB2.
Important Observations:
A) In my filter i am printing user roles. Even after step 4, my filter prints roles as [project1].
B) After step 3, it i stop filtered continuous replication and start it again, then after step 4, my filter prints roles as [project1,project2] and hence step5 becomes successful.

I dont want to restart filtered continuous replication after any change to role in _users DB. Is there any solution for this. I am trying to achieve 1 DB per user implementation.